# Combinations or permutations of input, for a given length

Tags: python, python-2.7, permutation

I have been trying to calculate all the permutations for two characters (E and L) as it happens, for a given sequence length. If I `import itertools` and run `itertools.permutation('LE', 8)` I get no output, obviously if i only pass `itertools.permutation('LE')` I will get the permutations that are two long ie LE and EL. Is there a way of running the permutations in such a way that I would have the arguments `'LE'` and a number, say 3 which would then result in:

```
LLL
EEE
LLE
EEL
LEE
ELL
ELE
LEL
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is a cartesian product `LE × LE × LE`.

Use `itertools.product` with the `repeat` argument:

```
In [60]: list(itertools.product('LE', repeat=3))
Out[60]:
[('L', 'L', 'L'),
 ('L', 'L', 'E'),
 ('L', 'E', 'L'),
 ('L', 'E', 'E'),
 ('E', 'L', 'L'),
 ('E', 'L', 'E'),
 ('E', 'E', 'L'),
 ('E', 'E', 'E')]
```

```
In [62]: [''.join(p) for p in itertools.product('LE', repeat=3)]
Out[62]: ['LLL', 'LLE', 'LEL', 'LEE', 'ELL', 'ELE', 'EEL', 'EEE']
```